# Biholomorphic function question

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I was solving this problem:

> Let $D=B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}$ and $B=B(0,1)\setminus 
>  \overline{B(0,\frac{1}{2})}.$ There is an biholomorphic function $f:D\to B?$

And the answer is no. This is easy to see using the Riemann principle we extend $f$ in $0$ and contradict the injectivity of $f$ using two disjoint opens set in the domain.

After that I was thinking if there are any other open set $U$ in complex plane such that there is a biholomorpginc function $f:B\to U.$

For exemple if $U=B(0,r)\setminus\{0\}$ then is easy to find an biholomorfism.

My first question, $U$ can be unbounded?

My second question, I true that if I take a simply connected open set from plane say $W$ and i remove a point say $w$ then $W\setminus\{w\}$ is the only exemple for such a $U$?

Comment: The map $1/z$ comes to mind.

Comment: @zhw. Thats right, didn't tough about that one :(

Comment: @zhw. If we count this case, those are the only cases? If yes, how one can prove this? I'm interested in this kind of question for the technique of finding all the sets with a center property.

Comment: If $V\ne\Bbb C$ is open and simply connected then it is equivalent to the disk. Hence $U=V\setminus\{p\}$ is equivalent to the punctured disk.

Comment: There's a theorem that says any doubly connected domain(a domain whose complement has two connected components) is biholomorphic to an annulus $A(r,R):=\{ z\in\mathbb{C}\mid r<|z|<R \}$ with  $0\leq r<R\leq\infty$. Furthermore, $A(r_1,R_1)$ is biholomorphic to $A(r_2,R_2)$ if and only if $\displaystyle \frac{R_1}{r_1}=\frac{R_2}{r_2}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why $U$ is equivalent to puncture disk?

Comment: Have you thought about this? There exists a biholomorphic map $f:B(0,1)\to V$ with $f(0)=p$. So the restriction of $f$ to $B(0,1)\setminus\{p\}$ is a biholomorphic map onto $V\setminus \{p\}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh, sorry for asking that :(